# Yii2 - Upload form error

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-file-upload

I need to implement an upload form and I using krajee's FileInput plugin :

http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput
this is my form view

```
<!--modal render for upload-->
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\widgets\FileInput;
use yii\helpers\Url;
?>

<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        ファイル&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="label label-warning">必須</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 file-input" bgcolor="#FAFCFF">


        <?= FileInput::widget([
            'name' => 'file',
            'model' => $model,
            'options'=>[
                'multiple'=>true
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['document/upload-file']),
                'uploadExtraData' => [
                    'parent_folder' => "22222",
                    'parent_id' => 13
                ],
                'maxFileCount' => 10
            ]
             ]);
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

when form load it said:

> You must set an input type = file for bootstrap-fileinput plugin to
>   initialize.

Please tell me what wrong?

//Update model rules

```
 public $extensions = [];
   public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['file', 'file', 'extensions' => $this->extensions, 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ,model rules updated

Comment: If you're using multiple version, try to add `'attribute' => 'attachment_1[]'`. Notice `[]`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set id

```
<?= FileInput::widget([
        'id' => 'fileUpload'
        'name' => 'file',
```